# Dynamic variables to store different value in a for loop in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying the below steps but it throws an error: '${dut1_lmepid_${i}}' no keyword found.

If I use anything like ${temp_var} in place of ${dut1_lmepid_${i}} it works fine though.

```
: For    ${i}    IN RANGE    1    2
\    ${var} =    Set Variable    dut1_lmepid_${i}
\    ${dut1_lmepid_${i}}=    Run Keyword    get-local-ac-id    me${i}
```

Comment: Please include the actual error in your question.

Comment: Why do you need to dynamically create new variable names? What's wrong with using `{temp_var}`? If you need to save all of the variables, have you considered using a dictionary or list instead of a bunch of generated variables?

Comment: Yes, I made use of list to store the values instead of creating dynamic variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do this using a second step using the keyword `Set Global Variable`:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Item
    :For    ${i}    IN RANGE    1    5
    \    ${value} =    Run Keyword    get-local-ac-id    me ${i}
    \     Set Global Variable     ${dut1_lmepid_${i}}    ${value}
    No Operation

*** Keywords ***
get-local-ac-id
    [Arguments]    ${arg}
    [Return]    value ${arg}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you cal also use Set Suite Variable and Set Test Variable in same way

Comment: Correct. The scope does not need to be Global, it can be Suite or Test level.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible with Robot. You can use "variables inside variables" to resolve the values of variables (see [the documentation on this topic](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variables-inside-variables)) but not to resolve/set the name of the variable itself.